# An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO proposition

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

The fact a user has several service and want to add a service user.
This is my entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="bundle\FrontBundle\Entity\Proposition", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    protected $propositions;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->proposition = new ArrayCollection();

    }
}

/**
 * Proposition
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="proposition")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Proposition
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="bundle\FrontBundle\Entity\Type", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    protected $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="bundle\FrontBundle\Entity\NomPrestation", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    protected $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="bundle\FrontBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="propositions", cascade={"persist", "merge"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    protected $user;

}


/**
 * Prestation
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="type")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Type
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $type;
}


/**
 * TypePrestation
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="nom_prestation")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class NomPrestation
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
     */

    protected $nom;

  }
```

My problem is this , when I add a first proposal and everything works fine when I add another I have this error.

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO proposition (prix, prix_main_oeuvre, type_id, nom_id, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [3442, 232, 1, 4, 1]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UNIQ_C7CDC353C54C8C93'

Can someone help me see more clearly ?

Comment: One of prix, prix_main_oeuvre, type_id, nom_id, user_id has `unique` constraint so you've added dupplicated entries.

Comment: the 'UNIQ_C7CDC353C54C8C93' key is for type_id @felipsmartins

Answer (score 0):

You have this error because a type with id `1` already exists.

I suppose you want to reuse the same type many times. If so, you have to change the relation between `Proposition` and `Type` from a `oneToOne` to a `oneToMany` one.

I suspect the same should apply to your `NomPrestation` relation. If you don't reuse these `NomPrestation`, you should consider add this as a property of `Proposition` instead of an entity.

Comment: thanx you !! i try this

Comment: @Darkness007 did it helped you?